# How to use Pandas to work on a data loaded from my own created class?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class, data-processing

I got a small problems on working with Pandas. The problem is I created a file that stores class to read and clean data from a .csv file. and I import my own library to load the data and then i want to use the pandas dataframe for other operations. But for some reason, I can't do it.

So, here is the code I created a class for loading/reading the file:

```
import pandas as pd

class Load_Data:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.__filename = filename

    def load(self): 
        df = pd.read_csv(self.__filename)
        del df["Remarks"]
        df = df.dropna()

    return df
```

and in another file, i was trying to import this self-created library for data processing step and then try to work on it with Pandas DataFrame.

```
from Load_Data import Load_Data
import pandas as pd

test_df = Load_Data("Final_file.csv")
test_df.load()
```

There is no problem printing the table of the content from my file. But when I tried to use it (test_df) as a Pandas dataframe, for example, I want to GroupBy some of the attributes

```
test_df.groupby(['width','length])
```

it ends up showing:

> 'Load_Data' object has no attribute 'groupby'

which means if i want to use the groupby function, i have to write it on my own in my own class. but I don't want to do that. I just want to convert my class to a Pandas DataFrame and work using their package directly for some complex operations.

I would be really appreciate for any kindly helps

Comment: You say you're getting an error, but you don't show the code that causes it (when you call groupby), so it's hard to help you. Please include the code that generates the error, and the _complete_ stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share the next line or two which throw an error?
Are you referencing the returned data, or the class?

I.e.

```
df2= test_df.load()
df2.groupby()
```

Or

```
test_df.groupby()
```

Are you trying to create a new data frame class build on pandas?
If so you'd need something like this (might work)

```
class LoadDF(pd.DataFrame)
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.__filename = filename

    def load(self): 
        df = pd.read_csv(self.__filename)
        del df["Remarks"]
        df = df.dropna()
        self = df
```

Comment: Awww, actually, many thanks to you! I tried the first one you've written and it works. Thank you so much!!! just a quick question if you or anyone would like to explain why I need an extra variable to make this happen?

Comment: Because the load method of the class returns a data frame. The instance it Load_Data that is called test_df isn't a data frame at all, but a class that loads a data frame.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! Maybe I should then change the 'test_df' to something else since i was misunderstanding the concept and thought it was a dataframe. really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You are using class as if it was a function. Push return statement inside `load` method

```py
import pandas as pd

class Load_Data:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.__filename = filename
        

    def load(self): 
        df = pd.read_csv(self.__filename)
        del df["Remarks"]
        df = df.dropna()
        return df # this change
```

Usage:

```py
test_df = Load_Data("Final_file.csv").load() #this change
# or
load_data = Load_Data("Final_file.csv")
test_df = load_data.load()
```

load returns a DataFrame and not a Load_Data instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping as well!